# Fix decimal numbers

Tags: android, gps

Now I;m receiving the GPS location data from android application, and send it to Labview.

However, the decimal number of gps location value changes due to the location.

I want to fix the decimal number such as 7

For example, what I get is 32.33333 but I need 32.333330

How can I declare the value?

Here is the gps value part

```
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener 
{

     private String gps2;
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
                if (loc != null) {
                   /* 화면의 상단에 위치한 TextView에 위도, 경도를 출력함*/

            gps.setText("La:"+loc.getLatitude()+", Lo:"+loc.getLongitude());
            gps2 = gps.getText().toString();
            Main.getInstance().sendMessage(gps2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
        Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing this way

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.000000");
gps.setText("La:"+numberFormat.format(loc.getLatitude())+", Lo:"+numberFormat.format(loc.getLongitude()));
```